# how to replace a string in html renderPartial?

Tags: html, knockout.js, renderpartial

```
                    @{ Html.RenderPartial(MVC.Shared.Views.Partials.CameraTagVideoPlayer, new CameraTagVideoPlayerViewModel("applicationVideo", "xxx")); }
```

I want to replace "xxx" with a particular knockout data-bind.

For example,

```
<span data-bind="text: application.applicationKey"></span>
```

gives me a applicationKey of a person. I want to put this key inside that RenderPartial to play a video. Is there a way to do this?

EDIT:

```
public static class Partials
{
    public readonly static string _CurvedSelector = "~/Views/Shared/Partials/_CurvedSelector.cshtml";
    public readonly static string SelectMonthOptions = "~/Views/Shared/Partials/SelectMonthOptions.cshtml";
    public readonly static string SelectStateOptions = "~/Views/Shared/Partials/SelectStateOptions.cshtml";
    public readonly static string SelectYearOptions = "~/Views/Shared/Partials/SelectYearOptions.cshtml";
    public readonly static string ToggleButton = "~/Views/Shared/Partials/ToggleButton.cshtml";
    public readonly static string CameraTagVideoPlayer = "~/Views/Shared/Partials/CameraTagVideoPlayer.cshtml";
    public readonly static string CreditCardFormFields = "~/Views/Shared/Partials/CreditCardFormFields.cshtml";
    public readonly static string CreditCardJavascript = "~/Views/Shared/Partials/CreditCardJavascript.cshtml";
    public readonly static string AntiBotFormFields = "~/Views/Shared/Partials/AntiBotFormFields.cshtml";
    public readonly static string ExitModal = "~/Views/Shared/Partials/ExitModal.cshtml";

}
```

cameratagvideoplayer.html :

```
@model CameraTagVideoPlayerViewModel

@{
    // CameraTag video security
    long expiration = Utilities.ToUnixTimestamp(DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(30)); // can be no more than 1 hour
    string signature = Utilities.CreateTokenHmacSha1(expiration.ToString(), AppSettings.Current.CameraTagRestApiKey);
}

<player id="@Model.Id" 
        data-uuid='@(Model.VideoUuid)' 
        data-options='{"width":"100%","height":"100%", "aspectratio":"4:3", "displaytitle":"false","displaydescription":"false"}' 
        data-signature="@signature" data-signature-expiration="@expiration"></player>
```

Comment: Could you show the partial view `MVC.Shared.Views.Partials.CameraTagVideoPlayer`?

Comment: @JoseLuis Just added! Does that help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If knockout is enabled when this view is redered, you could use the attr binding (http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/attr-binding.html):

```
<player id="@Model.Id" 
    data-bind="attr: { 'data-uuid': application.applicationKey }"
    data-options='{"width":"100%","height":"100%", "aspectratio":"4:3", "displaytitle":"false","displaydescription":"false"}' 
    data-signature="@signature" 
    data-signature-expiration="@expiration">
</player>
```

Hope this helps.

**Update 1**
This question is about Camera Tag (https://cameratag.com/).  This javascript library finds `<player>` tags with an onload event.  You can add new tags, but can't modify the existing ones.

You can create a custom binding that, on each change, creates a new `<player>` tag (and of course, delete the old ones):

```
ko.bindingHandlers.uuid = {
    update: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindings) {
        // First get the latest data that we're bound to
        var value = valueAccessor();
 //console.log(allBindings())
        // Next, whether or not the supplied model property is observable, get its current value
        var valueUnwrapped = ko.unwrap(value);
        var parentId = `${$(element).attr('id')}`
        var childId = `${parentId}_child`
        var childIdHash = `#${parentId}_child`

        // Delete de old <player>
        $(childIdHash).remove();

        var player = $('<player></player>')
        .attr('id',childId)
        .attr('data-uuid',valueUnwrapped)
        .insertAfter($(element))

        $.each($(element).data(),function (key, value) { 
          if (key !== 'bind' && key !== 'options'){
            var temp = value;            

            if (typeof(value) !== 'string'){
              // For example, data-options:
              //  data-options='{"width":"100%","height":"100%", "aspectratio":"4:3", "displaytitle":"false","displaydescription":"false"}'
              temp = {}
              $.each(value,function(key1,value1){
                temp[key1] = value1; 
              })
            }

            player.attr(`data-${key}`,temp);

            console.log(`x) ${key} : ${value}`); 
            console.log(value)
          }
        })

        CameraTag.setup();
    }
};
```

This binding also copy the `data-...` attributes of the original element.

Then, it can be used like this:

```
<player id="DemoPlayer" 
    data-bind="uuid: uuid"
    data-options='{"width":"100%","height":"100%", "aspectratio":"4:3", "displaytitle":"false","displaydescription":"false"}'
    data-signature="@signature"
    data-signature-expiration="@expiration">
</player>
```

And the ViewModel:

```
function ViewModel() {
    var self = this;
    self.uuid = ko.observable('v-1237c41f-9038-44b7-b4cc-8cb1f13f6f76')
}

ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());
```

Here is a [fiddle](https://fiddle.jshell.net/aa259m61/8/) to play with.  In the edit box you can change the key.  The key of this example is found in this url:  [player example](https://cameratag.com/demo).

Comment: <player id="applicationVideo" data-bind="attr: { 'data-uuid': application.applicantVideoUuid }" data-uuid="v-35b04706-458f-4791-a319-9d4c774c0f1a"></player>

it's weird. it does give me the data-uuid = applicationKey binding, but the video doesnt show up. Any idea?

Comment: @user7677413 I updated the answer.  The library you are using to play audio does de job of find the `<player>` tag on load.  Because of this, when Knockout gives the value, Camera Tag don't see it because it has yet scanned this `<player>`.  I add a custom binding that creates a new `<player>` each time the one handled by Knockout changes.  I add a fiddle to play.  Hope this helps.

Comment: You are my hero! Thanks!

Comment: btw how did you figure out that we cannot modify the existing <player> tag? Does it say it on the website

Comment: I don't remember the link, but I found one that says that this library search for `<player>` tags and replaces with an html5 player (JWPlayer).  One is instantiated, changes to this `<player>` are ignored.  In the website I found nothing about this, perhaps they think you will load all the `<player>` one time, and no need to delete them or rescan.